# how get date,time for calendar from sharedpreferences

Tags: android-studio

this store data in sharedPreferences

```
            SharedPreferences prefsDate = getSharedPreferences("Date", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefsDate.edit();
            editor.putString("Date", textDate.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            SharedPreferences prefsTime = getSharedPreferences("Time", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefsTime.edit();
            edit.putString("Time", textTime.getText().toString());
            edit.commit();
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Event", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edt = prefs.edit();
            edt.putString("Event", event.getText().toString());
            edt.commit();
```

here I put calendar but How I can get value for this (replace 0)?

```
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0 );
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Please follow the answers below @H.almamari

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think you need 3 separate SharedPreferences to store those 3 values.

Second, you cannot save a value as a String and then retrieve it later as an Integer. Change your code to something like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefsDate = getSharedPreferences("Calendar", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefsDate.edit();
editor.putInt("Date", Integer.valueOf(textDate.getText().toString()));
// save other values here
editor.commit();
```

Then retrieving them:

```
SharedPreferences prefsDate = getSharedPreferences("Calendar", MODE_PRIVATE);
int date = prefsDate.getInt("Date", 0);
```

Alternately, you could use my [SharedPreferences library](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/ORMPreferences) which could ease up things for you.

Comment: how to get value from sharedPrefrences?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of separating the date,month and year you can save it in a single String like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); // get the current year
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // month...
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day in the month
        String myDate=year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
```

Now you can save the whole String myDate in a sharedPrefrence and use it in your app:

To save the String write:

```
SharedPreferences prefsDate = getSharedPreferences("MyCalendar", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefsDate.edit();
editor.putString("Date",myDate);
editor.commit();
```

Now,to fetch the date string you should write:

```
SharedPreferences prefsDate = getSharedPreferences("MyCalendar", MODE_PRIVATE);
private String dateFromSharedPrefences=prefsDate.getString("Date","");
```